# AS3 Get width of player

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object, actionscript, width

This is located in public class to find half of the width of the player:

```
   public class Player extends MovieClip
{    
   private var playerHalfWidth:int = this.width/2;
```

I get this error:

```
1119:Access of possibly undefined property width through a 
reference with static type class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference `this` even before **Player** object is created.

Moving it into the constructor, would be the correct way :

```
public class Player extends MovieClip {

   private var playerHalfWidth:int;

   public function Player() {

     playerHalfWidth = this.width/2;
   }
```